# SharePoint 2016 Creating Service Application Error Request Timeout

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, sharepiont

I am getting error "Request time out" error while creating user profile service. SP Farm have 8 servers total.

- 2 Application
- 2 WFE (in DMZ)
- 2 Distributed Cache
- 2 Search

There is no helpful details in ULS as well.

Need Help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. Make sure the WFE servers do not have any trouble communicating with other servers and services.
2. Make sure you have login as the farm administrator account, and that it is in the local administrators group.
3. Disable any Anti-Vrius on the servers as well as firewall. Disable loopback check if necessary.
4. Run `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b force` on all servers and make sure all servers are in `no action required` status.
5. Try creating user profile service application [using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/08/powershell-to-create-user-profile-service-application-sharepoint-2016.html).

A similar post for your reference:
[SharePoint 2016 - Create Service Application timed out.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213013/sharepoint-2016-create-service-application-timed-out)